# Android studio doesn't work on windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated windows and attempted to launch the program, it started, but studio didn't see my emulators. After this i updated Android studio 4.1.2 and attempted to launch the program but It started but but then it closed itself.

It still remains in the task manager like background process, but no matter how long I wait, it no longer starts.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFXhy.png

I set the right path of "JDK_HOME" and "JAVA_Home" in the environment cariables.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ani4L.png

Checked if the Java.exe doesn't exist in C:\Windows\System32

I also tried reinstall Studio, but it doesn't help.

Do you have any other suggestion or or does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check if Android Studio will open after you run `studio.bat` in your `\bin` folder of Android Studio

Comment: it open, but did the same thing, in console it write: `code [ 334062]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:
2021-03-08 15:25:32,487 [ 334062]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.service.fus.collectors.FUCounterUsageLogger
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.internal.statistic.service.fus.collectors.FUCounterUsageLogger
        at com.intellij.featureStatistics.fusCollectors.LifecycleUsageTriggerCollector.onError(LifecycleUsageTriggerCollector.java:123)`

Comment: it seems that class `FUCounterUsageLogger` is the problem. Is this some kind of external plugin?

Comment: no, I don't remember installing one. How can i check that? And repair?

Answer (score 0):

I found what worked for me. qki gave me a hint what to look for, after that I came across a comment that this problem does not occur when launching the beta of AS 4.2 and it really helped, the studio at least started.